# Python Anaconda Error: NoPackagesFoundError: Packages missing in current win-64 channels:

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv

I am trying to install some Python packages on my system based on these [instructions here](http://forums.fast.ai/t/howto-installation-on-windows/10439). Running on Windows 10.

```
git clone https://github.com/fastai/fastai.git
cd fastai
conda create -n fastai python=3.6
activate fastai
conda env update
```

**Error:**

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .
NoPackagesFoundError: Packages missing in current win-64 channels:
  - spacy
  - expat
  - libxml2
  - pexpect
  - xz
```

**python --version**

```
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

**conda info**

```
            platform : win-64
        conda version : 4.2.9
     conda is private : False
    conda-env version : 4.2.9
  conda-build version : 2.0.2
       python version : 2.7.12.final.0
     requests version : 2.18.4
     root environment : C:\Users\y\Anaconda2  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Users\y\Anaconda2\envs\fastai
     envs directories : C:\Users\y\Anaconda2\envs
        package cache : C:\Users\y\Anaconda2\pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
          config file : None
         offline mode : False
```

What did I do wrongly?

Comment: Your conda version is very out-of-date, the current is 4.4.10. You may try updating conda first, as the answer suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the commands you show are not the steps suggested by the author of fastai. He suggests you:

1) Run Anaconda Prompt
2) Clone the repo
3) Run conda env update (which you seem to do after creating and activating a virtualenv)
4) Activate the new virtual environment.

That said, you may want to look into updating your Anaconda:
1) conda update conda
2) conda update anaconda

I tried this on my Windows 10 install, had the same error as you, updating did the trick. Good luck!

PS: there is one difference between our systems: I see you are on Anaconda2, while I use Anaconda3. If all else fails, you may want to look into switching versions.